# Logic for change in one column value in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an assignmentes table asg_tab with effective start date and effective end date columns which track on which dates which change was made.

```
asg_tab

eff_start_date      eff_End_date     PER_ASG_ATTRIBUTE2     job name  pos name
01-Jan-2015         03-feb-2015      Ck Bonus              Retail     Mgr
04-Feb-2015         20-Feb-2015      UK Bonus              Sales      Mgr
21-Feb-2015         28-Nov-2015      UK Bonus              Sales      Snr. Mgr
```

Now I have to calculate the number of days for which   PER_ASG_ATTRIBUTE2 is UK Bonus. For example in the above case it will be days between 04-Feb-2015 to 28-Nov-2015.

I have written the logic below, which is fetching values from cursor.

```
cursor cur_asg
 is 

select 
eff_start_date,
eff_End_date,
PER_ASG_ATTRIBUTE2,
job_name,
pos_name
from 
asg_tab
```

Logic I have built :

```
START_DT ='01-Jan-2015'
END_DT ='31-Dec-2015'
      IF PER_ASG_ATTRIBUTE2 LIKE '%UK Bonus%' THEN
     (
       l_new_ATTR = PER_ASG_ATTRIBUTE2

       l_effective_date = i.eff_start_date 


         IF  (l_new_ATTR <> l_old_ATTR) AND (l_effective_date >= START_DT ) AND (l_effective_date =< END_DT)
         THEN
         (


        l_days=eff_end_date -eff_start_date

         )
       l_old_ATTR = l_new_ATTR
    )
```

The issue which is coming up is that from this condition:  `IF  (l_new_ATTR <> l_old_ATTR) AND (l_effective_date >= START_DT ) AND (l_effective_date =< END_DT)`
This condition will pick the 2nd row where the  `PER_ASG_ATTRIBUTE2` changed from Ck Bonus to UK Bonus but when the pos name changes the 3rd row is generated. 
Even though the `PER_ASG_ATTRIBUTE2` is still UK Bonus this will not be filtered in the if condition.

What more can I add to this condition ?

Comment: How did you decide that you need to write a procedure for this? This looks like an easy job for plain SQL (which will run much faster too). Are you fixated on a procedure or will you consider plain SQL solutions?

Comment: This looks like a select for gaps and islands.  You can look it up "sql for gaps and islands".  There will be examples with what you need.

Comment: The assignment of  l_new_ATTR and l_old_ATTR  is in the IF statement and after the first time they will be always equal. (If this is in a loop of corse)

Comment: @Mottor Yes that is the doubt. How do i handle the gaps in dates

Comment: @mathguy- I want a procedure only for this. Which i have to call from another packege

Comment: You can do it with one select statement. See for sample here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38639006/oracle-sql-how-to-group-by-but-have-multiple-rows-if-group-is-repeated-at-a-lat/38639211#38639211